# Json File Will Not Load As A Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code I have in Python3. I have tried various methods, but I'm unable to pull the value from `"{\"fakeData\": \"fakeName\"}"`

```
        for files in listDirectoryFiles:
            with open(files) as json_file:
                data = json.load(json_file)

                # Print the type of data variable
                print("Type:", type(data))
```

This is the output:

```
Type: <class 'str'>
```

Comment: try a second `json.loads`. I suspect your data might be doubly encoded in JSON.

Comment: Or better, fix the source files instead (and whatever program used to write these files.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I just figured it out. I was doing a json.dumps in my Lambda function.